# Scroll automático hace variaciones de velocidad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

el scroll automático que aparece a continuación hace variaciones de velocidad en los distintos tramos y es muy importante para mí que la velocidad sea constante; cómo puedo resolver este problema? Es bastante evidente (al menos desde Google Chrome) esta diferencia pero si no la apreciais poned un crono al lado; gracias :)

```js
$(document).ready(
  function(){
        $("#stop").click(function () {
            $("#play").css({
   "opacity":"0.25",
   "pointer-events":"auto",
   "cursor":"pointer"
   });
   $("#stop").css({
   "opacity":"1",
   "pointer-events":"none"
   });
      $("html, body").stop();
        }); 
        $("#play").click(function () {
   var scrolli= $(document).height()- $(window).height()
            $("#stop").css({
   "opacity":"0.25",
   "pointer-events":"auto",
   "cursor":"pointer"
   });
   $("#play").css({
   "opacity":"1",
   "pointer-events":"none"
   });
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: scrolli },180000);
        });   
    });
```

```css
#dalealplay{
position:fixed; top:30px; color:white; font-size:12px; right:50px; line-height:5px; z-index:200; background:black; text-align:center; padding:5px;
}
#play{
opacity:0.25;
cursor:pointer;
}
#stop{
cursor:auto;
pointer-events:none;
}
.metro{
width:100px;
text-align:right;
color:red;
height:100px;
background:rgba(0,255,201,0.10);
z-index:0;
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dalealplay">
<span id="play">PLAY</span>/<span id="stop">STOP</span>
</div>

<div  class="metro">
_0
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la documentación de jQuery para [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) puedes ver los parámetros que se pueden pasar:

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

En tu función sólo especificas las propiedades a cambiar y la duración de la animación, necesitas indicar también el tercero: `easing`, que es una cadena que indica qué función debe utilizarse para la transición. El `easing` puede tomar diferentes valores que harán que la animación se ejecute de una manera u otra.

Por defecto el valor de `easing` es `swing` (lento al principio y final, y más rápido en medio), pero si quieres que la velocidad sea constante, debes especificar el valor `linear`.

Modificando eso, el código de la animación quedaría así:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: scrolli },180000, "linear");
```

Que dentro de tu código se vería así:

```js
$(document).ready(
  function(){
        $("#stop").click(function () {
            $("#play").css({
   "opacity":"0.25",
   "pointer-events":"auto",
   "cursor":"pointer"
   });
   $("#stop").css({
   "opacity":"1",
   "pointer-events":"none"
   });
      $("html, body").stop();
        }); 
        $("#play").click(function () {
   var scrolli= $(document).height()- $(window).height()
            $("#stop").css({
   "opacity":"0.25",
   "pointer-events":"auto",
   "cursor":"pointer"
   });
   $("#play").css({
   "opacity":"1",
   "pointer-events":"none"
   });
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: scrolli },180000, "linear");
        });   
    });
```

```css
#dalealplay{
position:fixed; top:30px; color:white; font-size:12px; right:50px; line-height:5px; z-index:200; background:black; text-align:center; padding:5px;
}
#play{
opacity:0.25;
cursor:pointer;
}
#stop{
cursor:auto;
pointer-events:none;
}
.metro{
width:100px;
text-align:right;
color:red;
height:100px;
background:rgba(0,255,201,0.10);
z-index:0;
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dalealplay">
<span id="play">PLAY</span>/<span id="stop">STOP</span>
</div>

<div  class="metro">
_0
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_100
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_200
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_300
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_400
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_500
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_600
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_700
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_800
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_900
</div>
<div  class="metro">
_1000
</div>
```

Comment: Buenísimo @alvaromontoro como siempre :)